# How to pass form data to another page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im using angularJS v 1.5.6 and want to know how to pass my form data correctly with $location.path.

Here is my code Page A:

```
<form>
...
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submit(formData)">submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {$routeProvider
// Home
.when("/", {
  templateUrl: "A.html", 
  controller: "ACtrl"
})
.when("/B/", {
  templateUrl: "B.html", 
  controller: "BCtrl"
})
  //fallback url if nothing matches
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
}); 
}]); 
app.controller('ACtrl', function ( $scope, $location, $http) {
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.submit = function() {
    $location.path("/B/" + $scope.formData );
};
});
//controller for B page
app.controller('BCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
function($scope,$routeParams) {

$scope.formData = $routeParams.formData;
}]);
```

it is a pretty simple example, but i cant figure out how to solve it :(

By clicking the submit nothing happens. If i remove the $scope from $scope.formData i get a error like: Error: formData is not defined.

The terms in formdata are available, i tested it with console.log($scope.formData) and everything is ok.

here is the link plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/K5zwcmRRyom5HR4a5Q9o

#### EDIT

the only issue is now, how to handle the select object correctly in the foreach loop. Need help please

Comment: Using $scope for passing data between pages is bad idea. Much more better is using service for sharing/passing data between different pages. You can create separate service formStateService and inject it into different controllers

Comment: please create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) so that we can edit it.

Comment: ok, plunker is available etc.

Comment: Use localstorage to acheive this.

Comment: any idea how to to solve the issue with the select object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a service and using setter/getter in order to transfer a variable. 
For example like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/IuTXsVLU7dq3TylfnSYP?p=preview

```
app.service('TransferService', [function(){

 var savedData,
 service = {
   getData: getData,
   setData: setData
 }

 function getData(){
   return savedData
 }

 function setData(data){
   savedData = data
 }

 return service
}])
```

Comment: thank you Evt.V it works pretty well. the only problem is to get the fromData output on the next page as wrote above. any idea?

Comment: In order to get data in any of the controllers you need to inject this service to the controller and use something like var formData= TransferService.getData(); Or maybe I don't understand your question? all the saved data is stored in the closure of service. If you want to render the data you can assign it to the scope. For example $scope.formData = TransferService.getData(); I updated the plnkr for you.

Comment: thank you very much @Evt.V i see. Can you help me please to calculate all values to one totalSum? is it easy possible? if not i am happy for every hint or link to achieve it. merci!

Comment: updated plunker. See CalcCtrl. This way you can calculate the sum of all values in this object if they are numbers

Comment: ok, i had added this stuff to my plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/K5zwcmRRyom5HR4a5Q9o?p=preview the problem is the selectoption object. here he cant get the id / integer correctly. other terms works great, but the select is ....

Comment: You can access the object like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/rfYa3y8prA1Jsm1v7iTt?p=preview I logged the id in console, but you can assign it to scope or save in closure and use however you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use location.path...**

You could either use a service or use localstorage (or some other browser storage mechanism [sessionStorage, indexdb].

**Service Method Below**

```
app.service("SomeService", function () {

    var value = null;

    this.set = function (val) {
        value = val;
        return this;
    }

    this.get = function () {
        return value;
    } 
})

app.controller("ACtrl", function ($scope, SomeService) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.submit = function() {

        //Assuming you've populated it with some data...
        SomeService.set($scope.formData);

        $location.path("/B/");
    };

})

app.controller("BCtrl", function ($scope, SomeService) {

    $scope.formData;

    (function () {

        //Check that the data is present in the SomeService service.
        var dataFromACtrl = SomeService.get();
        if (dataFromACtrl) {
            $scope.formData = dataFromACtrl;
        }
    })();
})
```

**Using localStrorage below, could be sessionStorage.**

```
app.controller("ACtrl", function ($scope, SomeService) {

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.submit = function() {

    //Assuming you've populated it with some data...
        window.localStorage.setItem("form_data", JSON.stringify($scope.form_data));
        $location.path("/B/");
    };

})

app.controller("BCtrl", function ($scope, SomeService) {

    $scope.formData;

    (function () {
        var dataFromACtrl = window.localStorage.getItem("form_data");
        if (dataFromACtrl) {
            $scope.formData = JSON.parse(dataFromACtrl);
        }
    })();
})
```

**Note**

Using the localStorage example you would need to do some clean-up, after doing whatever you want to do with that data in Bctrl you'd want to clear the entry in localstorage using either of the below lines of code:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("form_data");

delete window.localStorage["form_data"];
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i try it but it does not work. the redirect is okay, after i am in /B/ i get a erro: Error: $scope is not defined

Comment: @JohnDoo Please try again, I had missed adding "$scope" into both controller's dependancy parameters. The above code has been updated.

Comment: jep, that works fine. one question only, how to get the output on the B page? {{formData}} wont work

Comment: Which code are you using above? The service or the localStorage example? inside the if statement in BCtrl put a console.log($scope.formData) and see what gets shown in the console.

Comment: i try both of the. the console.log() works fine, but if i try to do this here on the second page, i get nothing: <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <pre>
            data: {{ formData }}
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Unsure why that would be happening to be honest, try adding a <div class="col-xs-12"></div> inside your row. So that the <pre> element is inside the <div class="col-xs-12"></div>

Comment: ok i achieved it to get the output. i insert the $scope.formData = formData; to put out {{formData}}. What i realy want to achieve is to get only the values. after that i want only make a addition of all values, like value1:3; value4:5 3+5=8. but i struggle here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123246/discussion-between-johndoo-and-lee2808).